# Implementing Source Control

Tags: version-control

My company has 3 developers.  Me, another guy, and a VP dev.  I really want to implement source control, especially since our code seems to randomly change on it's own.  We tend to develop on the server, live, etc.

I'm fine with having a copy of our database on my machine to work against, if necessary, as is the other guy.  The VP dev doesn't want it.  How can I work with him to change his mind, or make it work for him?

Comment: why not have a development database on the server which is backed up quite often? (like daily if possible, or at least to backup the table structure and such)

Comment: VP doesn't want source control, or doesn't want you developing against live data? Totally separate issue, and equally important to rectify.

Comment: Assuming the server is in house that is, else I would setup one of your machines to work as a DB server just for development

Comment: A now-deleted answer cross-references: http://www.web-articles.info/e/a/title/Keep-your-production-and-development-environments-separate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make him think it's his idea.

Point out that with source control you not only have a built-in backup of everything, but you also have the previous versions - let him realize how much of a good thing that is.

Comment: If he's an unreasonable person, this is THE answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and tell the one that opposes it that "everybody does it" :)
And seriously - source control is a MUST even for a single developer, let alone for three.

As for the DB server - you can use one development server (it can be a regular machine). It is of course no problem if you use each a local copy, but you must have a strong database schema generation/synchronization tools.

Comment: there's basically no reason to use a centralized SCM these days, and many reasons to use a decentralized one (even if the independence on the master repo isn't important, git and mercurial provide many conveniences that subversion lacks).

Comment: This is entirely subjective and saying "there is no reason" is simply wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should have source control. There isn't much excuse for not having it. Source control will protect you against changes that will cause problems in your code. I would recommend putting the db schema and data (sample set) in your version control. This will allow independent changes to the db without screwing up what your users see live on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're not really asking about source control here, but about where your development dataset resides. Local databases per-developer are best, if possible, but failing that, a reasonable alternative is to just have a virtual machine containing your source control server and a development database.

Comment: You could look into using a remote source hosting service as github.

Answer (score 0):

Putting things under source control is really easy - literally, 10 minutes from now you could have your source under source control.  Rather than try and persuade him the benefits I would just go ahead and do it anyway.

Start simply by putting a copy of your source under source control - even if he doesn't use it just merge the changes from live into your source control repository on a regular basis.  At least that way you have a revision history (and if you are him are the only people changing the source, it means that any changes you didnt make, he must have made)

With luck, slowly over time he will begin to see the benefits (**him:** oh no - everything just broke! **you:** Don't worry, I'll just look and see what has changed since the last working copy...)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to convince him that it is

1. Necessary to solve a problem,
2. an appropriate solution (does exactly what you need) and
3. easy to use.

It sounds like you have the information to demonstrate #1: the last time the code, "changed on its own," on the server and you lost someone's work or mixed results poorly. Bam, there's your "problem." #3 is the next more difficult: you need to pick an SCM with a good set of tools and do a demo. The TortoiseX line of products (TortoiseHg, TortoiseSVN) are great for this, because they make it non-scary.

Item 2 is the hardest: to demonstrate that this is the appropriate solution. Perhaps, to convince him of this, you might refer to anecdotes of other programmers or by looking at Github, where you can look back at previous versions of a product. I'm clutching at straws, here, because I feel like his argument will be, "Ach, and that's when it's a huge headache, is when things break. It won't be worth it."

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are a large number of ways to deal with people (and for the most part you have a "people") problem.

The first thing I'd do is find out why he's so against source control.  Often times people who don't like source control either don't like:

1. The extra work of committing
2. Don't always work next to an internet
3. See no extra value in it

There are different solutions to each of these problems.  Obviously the third one is tricky, so I'll handle it last.

If they don't like the extra work of committing, some chron scripts will help them (or windows scheduler).  Something that regularly commits in the background, or recursively goes through his files and adds them for the next commit.  This will mean you'll do a little more work on your end to clean up extra files and deal with broken builds, but its a step.  Alternatively if he's emailing you the code, a script that commits the emails works as well.

If he's not always working next to internet access, consider a system like GIT.  The advantage of GIT (over something like SVN) is that it utilizes a pull model instead of a push.  As a result you pull updates from other GIT users instead of pushing commits.  If you are working on a plane and don't have internet access, this is a valuable feature.

Finally, demonstrating the importance of the system is tough.  The best example is almost always: "My machine burned down."  I suppose you could nuke his box, but for the moment let's look at ways that don't piss off your boss.

A good way to demonstrate the importance of a repository is a Daily Build.  Having a daily build means you can readily integrate features and find bugs faster.  Setting up a repository with a daily build will significantly improve your work conditions, and its likely to make a good impression.

These are just a few of the reasons that people don't like source control, but the key idea is finding what his reason is and adapting to it.